# sigslot signals across threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I'm using sigslot library to trigger signals in a function. This function runs in a thread using QtConcurrent::run, and signals are connected in the main thread.
It's quite working as expected, except that the signal connection doesn't work every time (let's say around 25% failure).

This erratic behavior is problematic and I can't find a solution. Signals in sigslot library have different options depending on the multithreading context, but none of them is fixing the problem.

Before trying boost, I really would like to find a solution to keep using sigslot since it's a quite simple library and I only need a basic use of signals and slots in this part of the code. And I don't want to use Qt for this because I prefer to leave this same part of the code free of Qt.

Any hint would be much appreciated.

**Update :** for some reason, using as a desperate try sigslot::single_threaded appears to give way better results.

```
signal1<int, single_threaded> Sig1;
```

I'm not saying it's solving the problem since it doesn't make sense to me. As explained in the documentation :
*Single Threaded In single-threaded mode, the library does not attempt to protect its internal data structures
across threads. It is therefore essential that all calls to constructors, destructors and signals
must exist within a single thread.*

**Update 2 :**

Here is a MWE. But results are quite random. Sometimes it fully works, sometimes not all. I know it sounds weird, but that's the problem. I also tried boost::signals2 instead of sigslot, but result is quite the same. There's a executable bad access in boost::signals2::mutex::lock()

```
class A {
    public :
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
    sigslot::signal1<int, sigslot::multi_threaded_local> sigslot_signal;
    boost::signals2::signal<void (int)> boost_signal;
    void func_sigslot() {
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            sigslot_signal.emit_signal(i);
        }
    }
    void func_boost() {
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            boost_signal(i);
        }
    }
};

class B : public sigslot::has_slots<sigslot::multi_threaded_local> {
    public :
    B() {}
    ~B() {}
    void test(int i) {
        std::cout << "signal triggered, i=" << i << std::endl;
    }
};

void main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    a.sigslot_signal.connect_slot(&b, &B::test);
    a.boost_signal.connect(boost::bind(&B::test, &b, _1));
    QtConcurrent::run(&a, &A::func_sigslot);//->crashes when signal emitted
    QtConcurrent::run(&a, &A::func_boost);//->crashes when signal emitted

    boost::thread t1(boost::bind(&A::func, &a));
    t1.join();//works fine
}
```

Comment: sorry about not making a MWE, I was indeed rather looking for a global answer instead of a code debugging (like maybe "Qt and sigslot won't work together"). Since the behavior is erratic and context quite tangled I thought it wasn't worth making an exemple

Comment: The most important missing part is: there is no "the" sigslot library. It is an abandoned project available in multiple, er, stages of decomposition from various sources. Please add a link to the version you're using.

Comment: Well I didn't know this about this library. I started using because I found only good feedbacks about. I'm using this version : https://sourceforge.net/p/sigslot/patches/3/

Comment: There's no chance this will ever work, unless all the slots are thread safe. Specifically, `std::cout` is *not* thread-safe, so calling it from multiple threads is already undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that the patch you have is not necessary. `QT_NO_KEYWORDS` is the macro you need to add to your project's `DEFINES`, it fixes it. You're also using an old version of Visual Studio, that's the only compiler that takes the original sigslot code and doesn't complain. Original sigslot is not valid C++. I'll have an update available "soon" @ https://github.com/KubaO/sigslot

Comment: Thanks for the tip QT_NO_KEYWORDS. It is indeed convenient (no tested yet but I trust you 100%). I'm using Xcode 7 by the way, but I'm trying to install Visual Studio and test the code on it.

Answer (score 2):

The Sarah Thompson's sigslot library (if that's what you use) is old, unsupported, and seems quite buggy. There's no test harness of any sort. The original source doesn't compile under modern compilers. There are typos there that were hidden due to MSVC's former treatment of templates as token lists: obviously parts of the code were never used!

**I highly suggest that you simply use Qt, or a different signal-slot library.**

Alas, your approach can't work: the [sigslot library](http://sigslot.sourceforge.net) has no idea about Qt's thread contexts, and doesn't integrate with Qt's event loop. The slots are called from the wrong thread context. Since you likely didn't write your slots to be thread-safe, they don't do the right thing and appear not to work.

The sigslot library's threading support only protects *the library's own data*, not your data. Setting the multithreading policies only affects the library's data. This is in stark contrast with Qt, where each `QObject`'s thread context is known and enables the signal-slot system to act safely.

In order to get it to work, you need to expose a thread-safe interface in all the `QObject`'s whose slots you're invoking. This can be as simple as:

```
class Class : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Class() {
    // This could be automated via QMetaObject and connect overload
    // taking QMetaMethod
    connect(this, &Class::t_slot, this, &Class::slot);
  }
  Q_SIGNAL void t_slot();
  Q_SLOT slot() { ... }
}
```

Instead of connecting to `slot()`, connect to `t_slot()`, where the `t_` prefix stands for threadsafe/thunk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Qt connections looks to be ok for now. But you're right I didn't make any specific for the slots to be thread-safe. Problem is more related to sigslot connections, which signal is triggered in a Qt thread but connected in the main thread (along with the sigslot slot). But maybe I didn't understand your answer correctly.

Comment: Again, it doesn't matter what happens where, as long as the threads are different then sigslot doesn't support it. Read the documentation carefully: sigslot has no knowledge (and can't have any!) as to where do various object live. `QObject::thread()` is there for a good reason. Without such mechanism, thread-safe signal-slot system is impossible to implement.

Comment: Using boost in the MWE doesn't give any better result. The example you proposed using QObject is meant to be as a replacement for sigslot or boost right ? I really want to avoid using Qt in the computation library which is used in QtConcurrent::run, it's too heavy in case library is used without GUI. Anyway it's very weird, now in my code things appear to work fine (using sigslot), but I m not confident considering what you said. Software is supposed to be cross platform etc and I fear some weird behavior can appear anytime in the future

Comment: No, the example isn't a replacement, it's a requirement to get any other signal-slot library to access the QObject methods in a thread-safe way, assuming that all of your objects with slots are QObject. If your objects-with-slots aren't QObjects, you'll need to either make their methods thread-safe or reimplement a chunk of core Qt.

Comment: To recap: your concern is the target of a connection, the class with slots. If it is a QObject, then it has a known thread context and you should invoke is thunk signal, **not** the slot directly, from the sigslot library. If the connection target is not a QObject, you'll need to either make all the slots there thread-safe, or you'll have to run a (3rd-party) event loop in the target object's thread, receive functor-carrying events there, and execute them.

Comment: The concern for what thread you're calling your slots in has nothing to do with "incompatibility" between some 3rd party code and Qt, you'd have the very same problem if you weren't using Qt at all. That's why Qt's `QObject` has a `thread()` method. Classes that don't have that or a similar method have no chance to be transparently used by any signal-slot library. In C++, an object instance has no inherent thread affinity, so unless you add functionality that keeps track of that, your code will be broken (unless slots are thread-safe).

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still very confused about your explanation, despite your much appreciated efforts. Maybe I got it wrong again, but I'm not trying to connect a sigslot/boost signal to a Qt slot. In my general code, the main difference with the MWE is that B::test emits a Qt signal inside the function. And it's working every time now.. Making a not working MWE of a working code just drives me crazy

Comment: As long as the signal and the slot are in different threads, the slot must be either thread-safe or you must execute the slot in the slot object thread's event loop. That's all. This applies to any framework. Neither sigslot nor boost's signal-slot system do it for you automatically. Qt does.